# How to get information out of a list

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So iam coding an discord bot and i want to get information out of an list that looks like this and this output is in "information = await guild.invites()"

```
[<Invite code='GZqCe8EF' guild=<Guild id=847546806937059338 name='Testing' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2> online=None members=None>, <Invite code='jQ2HeQfx' guild=<Guild id=847546806937059338 name='Testing' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=2> online=None members=None>]
```

is it possible to get single things out like guild id or maybe 2 things like name and invite code and is it possible that u can output every line from it like the first invite code and the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output every invite code, you can use:

```py
for invite in information:
    print(invite.code) #invite.code returns the invite code, do whatever you want to do with it
    # you can also add invite.guild.name to for the guild name etc
```

To output only from one invite:

```py
print(information[0].code)
```

---

**References**

- [invite object with every possible paramenter after .](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=invite#discord.Invite)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, the `invites()` method returns list of `Invite` objects. To check what attributes does this object have look [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Invite).
to access an attribute you have to do this: `InviteObject.{name of attribute}`. Example:

```py
for invite in information:
    print(invite.guild.id)
```

It works the same for any discordpy object:

1. Look for the method that you are using in [discordpy docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) (In your case `invites()`)
2. See what does it return (In your case list of `Invite` objects)
3. Search for the object (In your case `Invite`)

Comment: Using list comprehension makes it a lot cleaner: `[invite.* for invite in information]`